# Why is my image not showing and in my metadata it says that my band is 0?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geocoding, landsat-8, digital-image-processing, band

I'm working on estimation chlorophyll-a using a Landsat 8 image on Google Earth Engine but my image is not showing, and in my metadata it says that my band is 0. I'm really really confused because I've tried to changing it but it's still not showing. This is my script https://code.earthengine.google.com/c5801d0cfbf5be8d44865892787bbe68

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Check out the tour here to get an overview of the site and some guidelines for posting: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour. Please edit your post to include the code rather than linking to it. This helps to keep the question relevant even if the link breaks and also makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: There was a chain of things wrong. I don't know how to effectively explain it in an answer that will help other people, so I'm just putting a solution here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/afdefa35ade74b6bd12ccec737644785
Note that I'm not sure why you're using Tier 2 data, I switched it to Tier 1 and also you should change to Landsat Collection 2.

Comment: thank you so much for your help